# How can I calculate the Jaccard Similarity of two lists containing strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, similarity

I have two lists with usernames and I want to calculate the Jaccard similarity. Is it possible?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911252/python-jaccard-distance-using-word-intersection-but-not-character-intersection) thread shows how to calculate the Jaccard Similarity between two strings, however I want to apply this to two lists, where each element is one word (e.g., a username).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I ended up writing my own solution after all:

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2))) - intersection
    return float(intersection) / union
```

Comment: The function will always return 0.0

Comment: @xyd Works perfect for me. Can you please explain?

Comment: Worth noting this calculation is different than the answer by @w2bo as this one does not divide by the set length union.

Comment: This answer is wrong. For example, `jaccard_similarity([1], [0, 1])` -> `0.5` and `jaccard_similarity([1, 1], [0, 1, 1])` ->  `0.25` however second one should be as similar or more similar than first one based on how you define the jaccard.

Comment: The solution is simple and elegant, but not 100% correct. You should change the corresponding line to : 
`union = (len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2))) - intersection`

Answer (score 32):

For Python 3:

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    s1 = set(list1)
    s2 = set(list2)
    return float(len(s1.intersection(s2)) / len(s1.union(s2)))
list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
jaccard_similarity(list1, list2)
>>> 0.5
```

For Python2 use `return len(s1.intersection(s2)) / float(len(s1.union(s2)))`

Comment: This will also give 0.0 as result. Return statement should be modified :  return float(len(s1.intersection(s2))) / float(len(s1.union(s2)))

Comment: For Python2 use: `return float(len(s1.intersection(s2))) / len(s1.union(s2))`

Answer (score 14):

@aventinus I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your answer, but just to make things clearer, your solution measures the `jaccard_similarity` but the function is misnamed as `jaccard_distance`, which is actually `1 - jaccard_similarity`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I did not know that. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your usernames don't repeat, you can use the same idea:

```
def jaccard(a, b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c))

list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
# The intersection is ['dog', 'cat']
# union is ['dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'mouse]
words1 = set(list1)
words2 = set(list2)
jaccard(words1, words2)
>>> 0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Distance](https://github.com/doukremt/distance) library

```
#pip install Distance

import distance

distance.jaccard("decide", "resize")

# Returns
0.7142857142857143
```

Comment: This answer describes how to get the Jaccard similarity between two strings which is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 3):

@Aventinus (I also cannot comment): Note that Jaccard *similarity* is an operation on sets, so in the denominator part it should also use sets (instead of lists). So for example `jaccard_similarity('aa', 'ab')` should result in `0.5`.

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(set(list1).intersection(list2))
    union = len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2)) - intersection

    return intersection / union
```

Note that in the intersection, there is no need to cast to list first. Also, the cast to float is not needed in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Creator of the [Simphile NLP text similarity](https://github.com/brianrisk/simphile) package here.  Simphile contains several text similarity methods, Jaccard being one of them.

In the terminal install the package:

```
pip install simphile
```

Then your code could be something like:

```
from simphile import jaccard_list_similarity

list_a = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog']
list_b = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat']

print(f"Jaccard Similarity: {jaccard_list_similarity(list_a, list_b)}")
```

The output being:

```
Jaccard Similarity: 0.5
```

Note that this solution accounts for repeated elements -- critical for text similarity; without it, the above example would show 100% similarity due to the fact that both lists as sets would reduce to {'dog', 'cat'}.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to include repeated elements, you can use `Counter`, which I would imagine is relatively quick since it's just an extended `dict` under the hood:

```
from collections import Counter
def jaccard_repeats(a, b):
    """Jaccard similarity measure between input iterables,
    allowing repeated elements"""
    _a = Counter(a)
    _b = Counter(b)
    c = (_a - _b) + (_b - _a)
    n = sum(c.values())
    return n/(len(a) + len(b) - n)

list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'cat']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']
list3 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']     

jaccard_repeats(list1, list3)      
>>> 0.75

jaccard_repeats(list1, list2) 
>>> 0.16666666666666666

jaccard_repeats(list2, list3)  
>>> 0.5
```

Comment: I think this solution is not correct as regards repeated items. However, it works ok for lists with non-repeated items.

Comment: I think that this is distance, so if one want similarity, '1 - ' should be removed from return line.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition of elements in the union (denominator), and a little bit faster I propose:

```
def Jaccar_score(lista1, lista2):    
    inter = len(list(set(lista_1) & set(lista_2)))
    union = len(list(set(lista_1) | set(lista_2)))
    return inter/union
```